# Decrypt video in fly and play

Tags: java, android

I need little help ..... Please help me ......

I am playing a encrypted mp4 video file from sdcard.
for this what i do .....

STEP 1. i copy file from sdcard in internal memory and 
       i write that file in world readable and world writeable format so that that i could Play

STEP 2. I decrypt that file in a temprary folder

STEP 3. now i play this , file plays no problem

Problem is this process takes time , because file is large about 25 mb , and this process ( copying and decryption ) takes about 2 minutes time

is there any solution , some thing like , file could decrypt in fly and play direct from that buffer .........

Please suggest me , what can i do , and if u have any demo link related to this than please mention here

Comment: Show some code. Do some research. Then come back to us.

Comment: You'd have to do something like streaming on the local stack ... I think the major issue here is if you can make it to decrypt parts of the file and work on them.

Comment: How is it encrypted? Or is it compressed?

Comment: Did you find any solution on the same, I am facing the same issue